# Counterclockwise in Eclipse Luna fails to see resources of a dependant project

Tags: eclipse, clojure, leiningen, eclipse-luna, counterclockwise

I have a project A that depends on project B. The poject B is a subproject of A and works as a part of project A. The project B has its own resources that it must access to bootstrap itself. So, when I start the project A, it fails with the exception that the assets for project B cannot be found.

This setup worked just perfectly in Kepler, it did not have any issues with finding the files, so all paths and source folders are intact.

Looks like something has changed in Luna, comparing to Kepler. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

**EDIT:** I also must add that the folder named "assets" exists in both project A and project B (they contain different assets). When I try to manually add the assets folder of project B to project A, Eclipse says that this folder already exists. Could this be the source of the problem? How do I resolve it then? Again, Kepler had no issues with that..

Comment: Do you use any build tool maven,ant or gradle?

Comment: @erhun yes, I use Counterclockwise for Clojure, which internally uses Leiningen which internally uses Maven...

Comment: are you able to run your project without eclipse? I mean can you compile and deploy it from terminal and then run your server and see the result

Comment: @erhun: thank you very much! thanks to your question I have managed to find the real cause of the problem! :)

Comment: yes i am always faced eclipse classpath issue when using maven so it is better to use this kind of tool, outside of eclipse, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @erhun, I have spotted the reson and the fix for the situation. As @erhun have queried, the project did not launch with Leiningen outside Eclipse with the very same issue. So it turned out that Counterclockwise was set to run the projects with Leiningen instead of the "defult java launcher", so I have changed it in the preferences and Eclipse did the magic.

Leiningen is known for its more strict policy on dependant projects, so it would not allow for such a kind of transitive dependancy, effectively making the user to copy all the resources into the main project.